# Kafka Elasticsearch sink connector task metrics or logs

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm facing an issue with `Kafka-Elasticsearch` `sink-connector`.
There are two topics to consume. For one of the `topic` (say `topic1`), its working fine with max 6 `tasks`.
For another `topic` ( say `topic2`), it works for sometime and then I see there are no consumer available and hence `message-behind` lag starts increasing.
I tried to search exception in `messages` and `kafkaconnect` logs but did not find anything.
The status of `tasks` is showing `RUNNING`.
Steps tried to make it work :
`connector` restart
`kafka-connect process` restart
Deleted and created the topic again.
But nothing solved the problem. On doing above steps, it works for some time and again it stops.
Tried reducing the batch size

```
        "linger.ms": "1000",
        "flush.timeout.ms": "1000",
        "connection.timeout.ms": "1000",
        "read.timeout.ms": "5000",
        "max.in.flight.requests": "10",
        "max.retries": "50",
        "batch.size": "1000",
        "retry.backoff.ms": "600",
```

`Kafka version: 5.5.0-ce` `Elasticsearch version is ES_V7`

I changed the tasks' log to `TRACE` but nothing I could find for failing tasks.
Any suggestion, what should I be checking ?

Thanks

Comment: Are these separate connectors, or you put 2 topics in the same connector with 6 tasks? How many partitions do each topic have?

Comment: @OneCricketer , thanks for responding 
those are two separate connectors. with 6 tasks each.

Comment: I see. So, some of those properties you've listed in the question are for producers, not a Sink Connector (consumer), and you need to prefix the properties if you actually want to override underlying client configurations

Comment: umm, I was under the impression that elastic kafka-connect is a sink connector 
Let me see what is about prefixing the properties 
thanks very much for responding

Comment: It is a sink. I'm saying that "batch.size", "max.in.flight.requests", "linger.ms", etc, for example, are all producer properties, and you have no Kafka producer involved here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I might be wrong though as I'm quite new to this but reading these properties from the link below seems consumer related too 

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/current/configuration_options.html

Comment: Ah, I see, they're using the same properties for the Elasticsearch HTTP client. Nevermind then. Anyways, regarding the problem. I really don't know. We've ran into similar issues where the consumer basically idles, but hooking up JMX metrics might give a better idea than logs alone

Comment: for one of the topic, reducing the max poll size helped but for another connector that is not helping either